# Problem with PGFPots wrt labeling both axes

Tags: pgfplots

I have a problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%xtick={0,1,...,10},
ytick={0,1*pi,...,3*pi},
domain=0:3*pi,
%scaled y ticks={real:3.1415},
ytick scale label code/.code={$\cdot Q$},]
\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100, color=blue]({x},{2*pi});
\addplot[domain=1:10, samples=100, color=red]({x},{2*pi/x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have something like this:

[image: PGFPlot corretto]

I'd like to cancel 3.14 and 6.28 values on y axis and substitute the 6.28-value with "$Q$", Moreover I'd like to cancel all values on x-axis and insert a "$R$" in correspondence with the end of blue line at the start of red function. I'd also like improve the space in the graph, I mean, the space between 3.14 and 6.28 is too wide. Is it possible?

**First Edit:** I tried to edit my code so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xlabel = $r$,
ylabel = $u$,
xtick={5},
xticklabel={$R$},
ytick={0,2*pi},
domain=0:3, y domain=0:10,
%scaled y ticks={real:3.1415},
%ytick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \pi$},
yticklabel={$\dfrac{Q}{R}$}]
\addplot[domain=0:5, samples=100, color=blue]({x},{2*pi});
\addlegendentry{$\dfrac{Q}{R}$}
\addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=white]({x},{x});
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot[domain=5:15, samples=100, color=red]({x},{10*pi/x});
\addlegendentry{$\dfrac{Q}{r}$}
\addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=white]({x},{x});
\addlegendentry{}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Now, my final problem is how to shorten the vertical axis and extend the horizontal where possible. How could I do? Thx again

Answer (score 2):

You could just define the length of the axis with xmax= and ymax=

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xlabel = $r$,
ylabel = $u$,
xtick={5},
xticklabel={$R$},
ytick={0,2*pi},
xmax=30pt,
ymax=8pt,
domain=0:3, y domain=0:10,
%scaled y ticks={real:3.1415},
%ytick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \pi$},
yticklabel={$\dfrac{Q}{R}$}]
\addplot[domain=0:5, samples=100, color=blue]({x},{2*pi});
\addlegendentry{$\dfrac{Q}{R}$}
\addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=white]({x},{x});
\addlegendentry{}
\addplot[domain=5:20, samples=100, color=red]({x},{10*pi/x});
\addlegendentry{$\dfrac{Q}{r}$}
\addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=white]({x},{x});
\addlegendentry{}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying but I haven't noticed any changes... Why?

Comment: The x axis is longer than the red function also the y axis is shorter isn´t that what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

- Sorry, but your question is not entirely clear.
- Why you use so old `pgfplots` version? Recent one is 1.18!
- The second MWE doesn't reproduce the first image. Are this means, that you after some else image?
- What you mean with "space between 3.14 and 6.28 is too wide"? It is defined by used function and height of diagram. So, do you like to reduce diagram height?
  ...

I guess, that you are after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,   % <---
             height=5cm,    % <--- 
             width=10cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $r$, 
    ylabel = $u$, ymin=0, ymax=3*pi,    % <---
    xtick = \empty,                     % <---
    extra x ticks={0,5},                % <---
    extra x tick labels={0, $R$},       % <---
    ytick={0,2*pi},
    yticklabel={$\dfrac{Q}{R}$},
    samples=100, no marks,              % <---
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick} % <---
            ]
\addplot +[domain=0:5]  {2*pi};         % <---
\addplot +[domain=5:15] {10*pi/x};      % <---
    \legend{Q/R, Q/r}                   % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- All changes in my MWE in comparison to your second MWE marked are by `% <---`
- If proposed solution not solve your problem, at least is without of (lot of) clutter in yours MWEs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution or, at least, this solution solves my problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.1.8}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18, height=5cm, width=15cm}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $r$, 
    ylabel = $u$, ymin=0, ymax=3*pi,
    xtick = \empty,
    extra x ticks={0,5},
    extra x tick labels={0, $R$},
    ytick={0,2*pi},
    yticklabel={$\dfrac{Q}{R}$},
    samples=100, no marks,
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
    ]
\addplot[domain=0:5, samples=100, color=blue]({x},{2*pi});
\addlegendentry[text width=10pt,text depth=9pt] {$\dfrac{Q}{R}$}
\addplot[domain=5:20, samples=100, color=red]({x},{10*pi/x});
\addlegendentry[text width=10pt,text depth=8pt] {$\dfrac{Q}{r}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

If you think this solution can be improved, I please you publish another one.
Thank you so much.